# Cannot resolve symbol error in xml layout (Udacity Sunshine Lesson 2)

Tags: java, android, xml

So I have this error message saying cannot resolve symbol in fragment_ main xml 
and it comes up on this line of code

tools:context=".MainActivity$ForecastFragment"> the ForecastFragment part of it is in red

please note the app still runs fine it's just that part of my code is in red and has error message. How can I fix this? Will this effect my code in the future while building this app? Below are the two java files main activity, ForecastFragment and xml as well. I tried Clean Code and it did not fix the error. Please help im new here.

```
package com.example.android.sunshine.app;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Encapsulates fetching the forecast and displaying it as a {@link ListView} layout.
 */





    public class ForecastFragment extends Fragment {

    private ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter;

    public ForecastFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Create some dummy data for the ListView.  Here's a sample weekly forecast
        String[] data = {
                "Mon 6/23 - Sunny - 31/17",
                "Tue 6/24 - Foggy - 21/8",
                "Wed 6/25 - Cloudy - 22/17",
                "Thurs 6/26 - Rainy - 18/11",
                "Fri 6/27 - Foggy - 21/10",
                "Sat 6/28 - TRAPPED IN WEATHERSTATION - 23/18",
                "Sun 6/29 - Sunny - 20/7"
        };
        List<String> weekForecast = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(data));

        // Now that we have some dummy forecast data, create an ArrayAdapter.
        // The ArrayAdapter will take data from a source (like our dummy forecast) and
        // use it to populate the ListView it's attached to.
        mForecastAdapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        getActivity(), // The current context (this activity)
                        R.layout.list_item_forecast, // The name of the layout ID.
                        R.id.list_item_forecast_textview, // The ID of the textview to populate.
                        weekForecast);

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        // Get a reference to the ListView, and attach this adapter to it.
        ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
        listView.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);

        return rootView;
    }

    public class FetchWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        private final String LOG_TAG = FetchWeatherTask.class.getSimpleName();

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // These two need to be declared outside the try/catch
            // so that they can be closed in the finally block.
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            // Will contain the raw JSON response as a string.
            String forecastJsonStr = null;

            try {
                // Construct the URL for the OpenWeatherMap query
                // Possible parameters are avaiable at OWM's forecast API page, at
                // http://openweathermap.org/API#forecast
                String baseUrl = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=94043&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=7";
                String apiKey = "&APPID=" + BuildConfig.OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY;
                URL url = new URL(baseUrl.concat(apiKey));

                // Create the request to OpenWeatherMap, and open the connection
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();

                // Read the input stream into a String
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                if (inputStream == null) {
                    // Nothing to do.
                    return null;
                }
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
                    // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
                    // buffer for debugging.
                    buffer.append(line + "\n");
                }

                if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                    // Stream was empty.  No point in parsing.
                    return null;
                }
                forecastJsonStr = buffer.toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error ", e);
                // If the code didn't successfully get the weather data, there's no point in attemping
                // to parse it.
                return null;
            } finally {
                if (urlConnection != null) {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
                if (reader != null) {
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                    } catch (final IOException e) {
                        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error closing stream", e);
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the Main Activity Code

```
package com.example.android.sunshine.app;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.container, new ForecastFragment())
                        .commit();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }


    }
```

Here is the Fragment_main xml file error is on this line  tools:context=".MainActivity$ForecastFragment">it says ForecastFragment cannot resolve symbol. Only the ForecastFragment part is in red.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"

             android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
             android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
             android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
             tools:context=".MainActivity$ForecastFragment">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview_forecast"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tools:context=".MainActivity$ForecastFragment"
```

The line of code in your XML is red because ForecastFragment is not an inner class of MainActivity. It does not affect your running code because the **tools:context attribute** is only used by the IDE to determine which theme to display in the layout preview/editor.

Below is the explanation from http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/tools-attributes

> **tools:context**
>
> This attribute is typically set on the root element in a layout XML
>   file, and records which activity the layout is associated with (at
>   designtime, since obviously a layout can be used by more than one
>   layout). **This will for example be used by the layout editor to guess a
>   default theme, since themes are defined in the Manifest and are
>   associated with activities, not layouts.**